# Chaining functions without callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function `deviceUpdate(ID, Token)` that I can call to update the list of devices for the user. This function does an ajax call where it displays a loading image until it is finished then displays all the info.

There is one particular time I would like to perform an additional (anonymous) function after the update is finished. How can I do this without embedding the anonymous function inside the deviceUpdate function?

Comment: Pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: You do it the same way jQuery does it all over the place: Make the function accept a callback.

Comment: I tried doing deviceUpdate(ID, Token, function(){}) to no avail.

Comment: You also have to change the implementation of `deviceUpdate` to call the callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Joachim Isaksson suggested, it can be passed in as a parameter.

Example:

```
function deviceUpdate(ID, Token,callback){
 $.post('url',data,function(response){ //ajax with jQuery post as example
   // your processing of response
    'function' === typeof callback && callback(); // if a function was passed in, run it!
 });
}


deviceUpdate(ID, Token); // for normal use

deviceUpdate(ID, Token,function(){
   // this is the anonymous function to be run in the special case 
});
```

Comment: Right, but that requires me to alter the deviceUpdate function. I know how to do that. I wanted to know if I could chain the function without altering the original.

Comment: @user3669154: For chaining, use promises and just `return` the value that `$.post()` yields

Comment: @Bergi Not sure what you mean, or that it's applicable. The function is not "mine" so changing it would require redoing work elsewhere. As for returning the value, it is returning an array of information that is being looped through and dynamically generating content based off that within the function itself.

Comment: @user3669154: Well, if `deviceUpdate` already does return something then you can obviously not use chaining. However, if the function does not offer a way to be notified about the asynchronous result, it needs to be modified anyway.

Comment: That's what I thought. That's unfortunate though. Thanks.